# Weird files in windows apps folder

Tags: windows-10

I've been wondering what were those weird files that I found in the windows apps folder (Appdata\Local\Packages).

In the microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Files\559\315 package, I have found a python program that I wrote together with photos of my facebook friends, renamed with weird names.

Can someone explain to me how all of this ended up here ? I'm really curious and I have no idea how this could happen.

Thank you very much !

Comment: 'The People, Mail, and Calendar apps are known collectively as the "Windows Communications Apps."' http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/communications-app-privacy The pictures of your friends are most likely from People. Have you emailed the python program to yourself or anyone?

Comment: That's what it is, I haven't even thought about it !